# Starting and Stopping a service on windows 2008 R2 through python script

Tags: python, windows-server-2008

I am trying to start and stop windows services through a python script on a machine running Windows 2008 R2.
The small piece of code I have in place is as stated below

```
import subprocess
import os
import time,datetime

p = subprocess.Popen("sc.exe stop ABC", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: what is the issue this command, works fine for me..

Comment: Which operating system are you using? The code works fine on Windows 7 but not on Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: ohk, i am using this on windows 7. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: No error just that nothing happens.Whereas using the same code one can see the service being started/stopped on platforms other than windows 2008 R2